# Is it possible to have multiple jenkinsfile and custom name for jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My whole scripts are in one branch of repo and I have multiple jenkins pipeline job.

```
1. smoke
2. Regression
3. Epic wise Execution
```

each have a different pipeline script. So is it possible to have multiple jenkins file with custom name ?

```
pipeline {
    node('Slave-Machine-1') {
        env.NODE_HOME="${tool '8.9.4'}"
        env.PATH="${env.NODE_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
        def AUTO = ''

        stage("Install Dependency") {
            sshagent(['agent-id']) {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run webdriver-install'
            }
        }

        stage("smoke") {
            sh 'npm run smoke-test'
        }
    }
}
```

This is my sample pipeline script. similarly i have multiple pipeline scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name your pipeline scripts `random_joe` or anything you like as long as:

- You do not use multibranch or organization pipeline projects, which specifically look for the filename `Jenkinsfile`  to automatically create new jobs
- You do not mind your text editor not syntax highlighting the pipeline scripts until you add the extension `.groovy` to them

It is advisable to follow conventions wherever not impracticable though.

Comment: You can configure at least the Multibranch Pipeline to search for a different filename, but it still has to be the same across all the branches.